# To understand: From PHP Array to Python?

Tags: php, python, arrays, loops

This is Common task In PHP and other programming languages.I moved from PHP developer.
I want to make sure with this collections.
Anyone have who good in python please help me to understand clearly .
This is my collections from PHP code.

```
<?php
$php = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
for ($i = 0; $i < 10 ; $i ++)
echo $php[$i]."<br>";
?>
```

=>What is in Python?

```
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i < 10 ; $i ++)
echo $php[$i] = $i +1 ;
?>
```

=>What is in Python?

```
<?php
$php = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
foreach ($php as $value)
echo $value."<br>";
?>
```

=>What is in Python?

```
<?php
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    $value = $value * 2;
}
// $arr is now array(2, 4, 6, 8)
?>
```

=>What is in Python?

```
<?php
$arr = array("mot"=>"one", "hai"=>"two","ba"=> "three");
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br />\n";
}
?>
```

=>What is in Python?

```
<?php
$arr = array("one", "two","three");
while (list($key, $value) = each($arr)) {
    echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br />\n";
}
?>
```

=>What is in Python?

```
<?php
$arr = array("one", "two","three");
while ($element = each($arr)) {
    echo "Key: $element['key']; Value: $element['value']<br />\n";
}
?>
```

=>What is in Python?

```
<?php
$products = array( array("ITL","INTEL","HARD"),
                        array("MIR", "MICROSOFT","SOFT"),
                        array("Py4C", "pythonkhmer.wordpress.com","TUTORIAL")
                         );
for ($row = 0; $row < 3; $row++)
{
    for ($col = 0; $col <3; $col++)
        {
         echo "|".$products[$row][$col];
         }
echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

=>What is in Python?

Comment: Don't try to translate your collection of let's call them "patterns" into Python directly, you will probably produce code that's very [unpythonic][1].  Instead, take the time to learn about the basic Python data structures first before you jump the keyboard.

  [1]: http://faassen.n--tree.net/blog/view/weblog/2005/08/06/0

Comment: Note that instead of saying `$php = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);` you can use `$php = range(1,10);` (and the same in Python actually).

Comment: @therefromhere:  At least in Python that's range(1,11), i.e. n+1 for the upper bound.

Comment: @python: Any reasons why you un-accepted my answer? :)

Comment: @intgr looks like he blogged your answer

Comment: Because you make me understand clearly.about looping in python ,array,multi array.list,and dict.Now I have the concepts.from php to python.Thank you again.
Any reasons why you un-accepted my answer? :) How Can I do?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

All of these are quite obvious really. I'm only listing the *Pythonic* ways to do these things. Update: Examples should now work in both Python 2 and Python 3. In Python 2 you could substitute xrange() for range() and iteritems() for items() for efficiency.

#### Example 1

PHP

```
$php = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
for ($i = 0; $i < 10 ; $i ++)
echo $php[$i]."<br>";
```

Python (generally you *iterate* over lists in Python, instead of accessing by index):

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for item in lst:
    print(str(item) + "<br>")
```

#### Example 2

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10 ; $i ++)
echo $php[$i] = $i +1 ;
```

Python:

```
lst = range(1, 11)
for item in lst:
    print(item)
```

Or maybe:

```
lst = []
for i in range(10):
    lst.append(i + 1)
    print(lst[-1])     # prints out last element
```

#### Example 3

```
$php = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
foreach ($php as $value)
echo $value."<br>";
```

Same as 1st

#### Example 4

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    $value = $value * 2;
}
```

Python:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
lst = [val * 2 for val in lst]
```

#### Example 5

```
$arr = array("mot"=>"one", "hai"=>"two","ba"=> "three");
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br />\n";
}
```

Python (note that `{...}` creates a **dict** [dictionary] in Python, not a list/):

```
dct = {'mot': 'one', 'hai': 'two', 'ba': 'three'}
for key, value in dct.items():
    print("Key: %s; Value: %s<br />" % (key, value))
```

#### Example 6

```
$arr = array("one", "two","three");
while (list($key, $value) = each($arr)) {
    echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br />\n";
}
```

Python:

```
lst = ['one', 'two', 'three']
for key, value in enumerate(lst):
    print("Key: %d; Value: %s<br />" % (key, value))
```

#### Example 7

```
$arr = array("one", "two","three");
while ($element = each($arr)) {
    echo "Key: $element['key']; Value: $element['value']<br />\n";
}
```

There is no direct Python equivalent to this.

#### Example 8

```
$products = array( array("ITL","INTEL","HARD"),
                        array("MIR", "MICROSOFT","SOFT"),
                        array("Py4C", "pythonkhmer.wordpress.com","TUTORIAL")
                         );
for ($row = 0; $row < 3; $row++)
{
    for ($col = 0; $col <3; $col++)
    {
        echo "|".$products[$row][$col];
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Python:

```
products = [['ITL', 'INTEL', 'HARD'],
    ['MIR', 'MICROSOFT', 'SOFT'],
    ['Py4C', 'pythonkhmer.wordpress.com', 'TUTORIAL']]

for product in products:
    for item in product:
        print('|' + item)
    print('<br>')
```

Or maybe a more Pythonic version:

```
for product in products:
    print('|%s<br>' % ('|'.join(product)))
```

Comment: If the first example really iterates over integers str(item) needs be used when printing those values.

Comment: this shows clearly how python syntax is less verbose and more clear that php IMHO

Comment: This want I am looking for...
Thankssssssssssssssss

Comment: One important difference between associative arrays in PHP and dicts in Python is that the order of an associative array in PHP is just as you set it whereas with Python's dicts their order is arbitrary, or rather, they are simply unordered. This along with PHP's totally awesome documentation is all I miss from PHP. Otherwise I'm a happy Python newbie.

Comment: I would have liked seeing xrange somewhere, for example in ex. 2. for item in xrange(1,10): . That looks even a bit more clean.

Comment: @extraneon: I added another Python version to 'example 2'. You're right, the previous code probably didn't do it quite the way the asker expected.

Comment: For iterating the array in example 5 the method `iteritems()` must instead be `items()` from Python version 3 forward.

Comment: @donut Starting in Python 3.6, dict keys are now order-preserving. But this is an implementation detail and should not be relied on.

Comment: This makes me hate python tbh, PHP has one thing, an array.  It can do anything without limitations.  You don't have to wrap your data structures in functions simply to iterate over them.  You don't have to wrap them in functions again to print them.  You don't have to memorize methods for lists, sets, tuples, counters, dictionaries, and the up and coming underwear and potatoes data structure or wtv they come up with next.  PHP is very simple and powerful, simplicity > unnecessary complexity.  Basically, python is MORE verbose and complex not less.

Answer (score 10):

"What is in Python?", quite a philosophical question, always a great way to start a day. I think what *is in* Python can best be answered by the Zen of Python (type `import this` in an interactive shell):

- Beautiful is better than ugly.
- Explicit is better than implicit.
- Simple is better than complex.
- Complex is better than complicated.
- Flat is better than nested.
- Sparse is better than dense.
- Readability counts.
- Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
- Although practicality beats purity.
- Errors should never pass silently.
- Unless explicitly silenced.
- In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
- There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
- Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
- Now is better than never.
- Although never is often better than *right* now.
- If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
- If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
- Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!

Sorry, couldnt resist. To answer the question you meant to ask, I direct you to the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/contents.html), specifically the section about [looping techniques](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) as linked to by [lutz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781617/to-understand-from-php-array-to-python/1781645#1781645).

Unless the syntax in the documentation manage to completely confuse you (though I doubt it) you will see how a loop is defined in Python. And once you have understood that, you will understand, by definition, how they differ (syntactically) from the loops youre used to in PHP.

Still not satisfied? Hmm... I guess you should read the tutorial *again*. Then, come back and ask specific questions that could yield specific answers. You wont find any silver bullets for a question this broad.

Comment: Thanks you very much.thank you all of you.I always welcome...:)

Comment: +1: "Then, come back and ask specific questions that could yield specific answers."  This is really the issue with this question.  It seems the author didn't realize that this is a broad topic about how looping and data structures work in Python, and not a specific problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can read an introduction to loops in [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques).

Comment: Thanks Lutz .If you can give me a corresponding code (php->python).
what I post here it would be great.

Comment: I am quick learn.i am switch from php to python for a while.
thanks.

Comment: If you are learning quickly, you should be able to answer your question on your own after reading the Python tutorial.

Comment: In fact.I am reading now.when u sent to me ,thanks.but at here people are motivate to share quickly,when I am in reading your link.other people make uderstand very quick..
Thanks Lutz alotsss

Answer (score 0):

This question reminds me of a wise man who had said, *"Give a man a fish; you have fed him for today. Teach a man to fish; and you have fed him for a lifetime..."*

Comment: I think this quote is not relevant to this question. Having comparable examples is a good tool for learning. That's all these are -- examples -- the asker didn't want us to solve his problems for him.