# How to make a string-based multi-dimensional array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm working on practising some Python, and I've encountered an error from trying to apply my previous PHP understanding of multidimensional arrays into Python's arrays.

```
maze_path = [
    [
        "You are in a forest looking into the shrubbery while sitting on a plane. Do you decide to check it out?",
        "yes:Walking in.." = [

        ],
        "no:END_GAME" = []
    ]
]
```

This is the array that I'm trying to setup, an array with more than one resolutions that can be iterated through to move to the next areas depending on a set of instructions that are given to the iterator.

I tried to execute my code and ran into the following error (was trying to see if syntax was legitimate):

> File "menu.py", line 159
>       "yes:Walking in..": [
>                         ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I tried changing the `=` sign into `:`, `==` **(comparison, worked but not as I expected...)** and just nothing with it.

What I am planning on doing with this is iterating on the first level of the array, something like so:

```
for instruction, resolution in maze_path:
  #// do some stuff with each of these informatants
  manage( instruction, resolution, maze_path )
```

Then from that I'll figure out some other issue to do with moving through the array.

**The main question**: Am I able to make string-based multidimensonal arrays in Python?

Comment: If you want an associative array in Python, that's `dict`.

Comment: The errror message is not about multidimensionality or arrays or dicts; it's about an assignment you make in the middle of an array constant. And addionally, this assignment has a string constant as ist LH-value - so in short: what are you trying to do there, Independent from the programming language?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781617/to-understand-from-php-array-to-python

Comment: PHP arrays are not like Python `list` objects. They are sort of a hybrid between Python `list` and `dict` objects. Among Pythonistas, "array" usually means `numpy.array`, which is a true multidimensional array data-structure. It can also mean the built-in `array.array`, but you shouldn't refer to `list` objects, e.g. `[1,2,3]` nor `dict` objects, e.g. `{'a':1, 'b':2}` as "arrays"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `dict` structure.  You can access a set of (`key`,`value`) tuples with `.items()`, and iterate over those pairs:

```
maze_path = {
    "You are in a forest looking into the shrubbery while sitting on a plane. Do you decide to check it out?":
    {"yes": "Walking in..",
     "no": "END_GAME" 
    }
}

def manage(i, r):
    print("     You chose {}, this happens: {}".format(i, r))

for description, options in maze_path.items():
    print(description)
    for instruction, resolution in options.items():
        manage(instruction, resolution)
```

Output:

```
You are in a forest looking into the shrubbery while sitting on a plane. Do you decide to check it out?
     You chose yes, this happens: Walking in..
     You chose no, this happens: END_GAME
```